# Is it possible to remove certain Result Types in SharePoint online?

Tags: search-results, site-settings

In the "Manage Result Types" settings there are certain result types that don't prove useful and make the search experience overloaded. E.g. I would like to remove SharePoint list items but it doesn't seem like there are options to remove them.
Am I looking in the wrong place? Is this even possible?